# margin: auto auto;

Tags: html, margin

Is this one working?

```
margin: auto auto;
```

I've used it but it doesn't centered on vertical, but does on horizontal.

as a supplement I did change the first auto with constant size, but still I need to make it auto coz I have dynamically changing elements.

Answer (score 0):

It's working as expected. [`margin: auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/margin) never *vertically* centers.